# Best/Fastest way to iterate through all sub-matrices of a NxN matrix

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix

I have a square board (NxN matrix). Each square (cell) has a certain points associated to it. My goal is to find the largest sub-matrix which has the highest summation of points. I started off with trying to find all the sub-matrices and their weights. But I am stuck on how to go about doing it.

I thought I could have a `HashMap<String,Integer>` which stores the initial row,column and the size of the sub matrix. The code should look something like this:

```
int [][] mat = new int[10][10];

void countSubMatrix()
{
    for(int i = 0; i<mat.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j<mat[i].length; j++)
        {
            storeSubMatrix(i,j);
        }
    }
}

void storeSubMatrix(int x, int y)
{
    int size = 0;
    int tempX = x;
    int tempY = y;
    while(tempX < board.length && tempY < board[x].length)
    {
        map.put(x.toString() + "," + y.toString(),size+1);
        tempX++;
        tempY++;
    }
}
```

But I don't know if this is the right way to do it. Any thoughts?

Comment: Do the sub-matrices have to be square too? Can they be any size less than NxN? Can the cell values be negative?

Comment: They have to be square too. And yes, any size less than NxN. Well, in my game there are no negative values but that is a good question though. How would it matter if a cell has negative value?

Comment: @noMAD: If there are no negative values, the answer is trivial - the complete matrix [which is by definition also a submatrix of itself] has no less summation then any of its submatrixes - thus it is maximal. However - I doubt that this is what you are really after...

Comment: Finding all the submatrices sounds like a job for recursion. But as the others have said its probably not going to get you what you're after in the bigger picture?

Comment: @amit: That's true. I was being silly. I need to change stuff in my design. Anyways, I will be having negative numbers in the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Largest submatrix ,i.e, it can also be a rectangle, then [this](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/UVa_108) might be of help to you. Using kadane's algorithm for matrix it can be done in `O(n^3)`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the O(n^2) solution?

Comment: @noMAD, sorry I confused this with some other problem. I don't think it is possible in less than O(n^3).

Comment: Alright, I would like to know how it can be done in O(n^3)??? How will you apply Kadane's algorithm here?